# Why does it says "Unrecognized name: start_station_id at [21:17] "

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

```
SELECT
    station_id,
    name, 
    number_of_riders AS number_of_riders_starting_at_station
FROM
    (SELECT
         CAST(start_station_id AS STRING),
         COUNT(*) num_of_rides
     FROM 
         `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips`
     GROUP BY
         start_station_id
    ) AS station_num_trips
INNER JOIN
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations` 
          ON station_id = start_station_id
ORDER BY 
    number_of_rides DESC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twxuE.png)

I'm trying to learn `INNER JOIN` function, I keep getting this error:

> The name is not recognizable,

but it is 100 % accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a column alias in the subquery

Once you use the CAST function on that column it no longer has a viable column name for the remainder of the query:

```
SELECT
      d.station_id
    , d.name
    , s.number_of_riders AS number_of_riders_starting_at_station
FROM (
    SELECT
          cast(start_station_id AS STRING) AS start_station_id /* alias needed here! */
        , COUNT(*) num_of_rides
    FROM bigquery - PUBLIC - data.new_york.citibike_trips
    GROUP BY
          cast(start_station_id AS STRING)
    ) AS s
INNER JOIN bigquery - PUBLIC - data.new_york.citibike_stations AS d
    ON d.station_id = s.start_station_id
ORDER BY d.number_of_rides DESC
```

I would also encourage you to provide brief table aliases so that all column references can be conveniently tagged by their source